# Explanation for Raoults Law

Tags: thermodynamics, solutions, solvents, vapor-pressure, colligative-properties

The vapour pressure of pure liquids is independent of quantity of substance.

But when in a solution, the vapour pressure of the components are given by
$$P_A=P^°_AX_A$$$$P_B=P^°_BX_B$$

Since $A-A$, $A-B$ and $B-B$ interactions are assumed to be equal for an ideal solution:

1. In case of liquid-liquid solutions how does it affect the vapour pressure(like whats is mechanism at molecular level). I presume it has something to do with volumes of both liquids being added as a result of which it is kind of like each liquid occupying a larger volume than permitted so making is somewhat similar to effect on gaseous equilibrium upon adding inert gas at constant pressure **But I  hope someone might provide a better,  more intuitive explanation.**
2. In case of non-volatile solid solutes, I cannot think of any explanation. Since solids occupy intermolecular spaces of liquids, there is no change in volume of solution, so **it should essentially have no effect on its vapour pressure similar to adding inert gas at constant volume to gaseous equilibrium.**

***Please explain with intuition why vapour pressure is not independent of concentration.***

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the easy answer, a solid can attract and absorb a liquid. For example, $\ce{CaCl2}$ is [hygroscopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygroscopic), and is sold [packaged](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078Y2TVN2) to reduce humidity in enclosed locations. Simply think, water molecules are more attracted to $\ce{CaCl2}$ than to the space above.

For liquids in liquids, consider those same intermolecular forces. For example, 100 mL of ethanol ($\ce{C2H5OH}$) + 100 mL of water ($\ce{H2O}$) combine to take up [~4% *less* volume](https://www.carolina.com/teacher-resources/Interactive/chemistry-lost-volume-demonstration/tr10785.tr). Again, thin of it as ethanol  being more "attracted" to water than to air.

BTW, [surface tension is similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension), in that one measures *cohesion* of a liquid compared to *adhesion* to an interface.

Answer (score 1):

The lower molar fraction of the volatile liquid A, regardless of if the other component B is volatile or not, means the lower rate of the liquid A evaporation.

It can be easily imagined that there is a lower number of molecules on the surface unit and therefore lower molecular evaporation rate

\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}N_\text{A}}{\text{d}t \cdot \text{d}A} &= k_\text{A,f} \cdot N_\text{A} &- k_\text{A,b} \cdot p_\text{A}\\
&= k_\text{A,f} \cdot N^\circ_\text{A} \cdot x_\text{A}  &-k_\text{A,b} \cdot p_\text{A}
\end{align}

At equilibrium, the rate of evaporation and condensation is equal.

\begin{align}
k_\text{A,f} \cdot N^\circ_\text{A} \cdot x_\text{A}   = k_\text{A,b} \cdot p_\text{A}\\
k_\text{A,f} \cdot N^\circ_\text{A}   = k_\text{A,b} \cdot p^\circ_\text{A}
\end{align}

---

Legend:

- $N_\text{A}$ is molecular surface density of the component A.
- $N^\circ_\text{A}$ is molecular surface density of the *pure*component A.
- $t$ is time.
- $A$ is surface area.
- $k_\text{A,f}$ is the evaporation kinetic constant for given temperature.
- $k_\text{A,b}$ is the condensation kinetic constant for given temperature.
- $p_\text{A}$ is the partial pressure of the component A.
- $x_\text{A}$ is molar fraction of the component A.